# Why am I getting this 401 unauthorized error while using Hammock with the Tumblr API to retrieve likes?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, tumblr

Here is the code that I am using:

```
        public static void FetchXML()
        {
            _url = new Uri("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + _username + ".tumblr.com/likes?api_key=REc3Z6l4ZYss11a8lX6KKje0X8Hsi9U77SyaPbQrOBBCGJGA6D");

            var client = new RestClient();
            client.Authority = _url.ToString();

            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.AddParameter("limit", "20");
            request.AddParameter("offset", _offset.ToString());

            var response = client.Request(request);
            var content = response.Content.ToString();
            var parsedResponse = JsonParser.FromJson(content);
        }
```

If I take the Uri value and paste it into my browser (using a valid Tumblr username) I'm getting the correct Json, but in my application the content of `response` is:

```
    "{\"meta\":{\"status\":401,\"msg\":\"Unauthorized\"},\"response\":[]}"
```

Anyone have any idea why this is? According to the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)
retrieving likes should only need the API key, which I am providing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the below code to get the response.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "Application/json";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream receive = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receive, Encoding.UTF8);
            string respond = reader.ReadToEnd();
```